# mDNS/jmDNS and domains other than local

Tags: dns, resolve, jmdns, mdns

I'd like to use mDNS as a resolving mechanism in a segregated network. To achieve that I'd like to use fully qualified DNS *without* the default *local* post-fix.
I've been through all the tooling (dns-sd CLI, avahi, jmDNS) that is out there for mDNS. But none seems to do the job. While jmDNS doesnt complain when publishing the following service.

```
val serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create("_http._tcp.example.com", "test", 80, "test")
```

None of the Tools listed above is able to resolve it. Am I just doing it wrong? I haven't really found and Information on why it should or should not work.

Thank you for any hints on this!

Comment: Will something like [`xip.io`](http://xip.io/) suit your needs?

Comment: @isim Not really, as I'm looking for an internal (private Network) solution to that problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this configuration:

Both alice and bob have debian avahi-daemon version 0.7-3.

```
# /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf
[server]
domain-name=happy.me
[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=no
```

Now if alice has avahi-utils, can test with `avahi-resolve-host-name bob.happy.me`, that will give bob's address.

Then have libnss-mdns version 0.10-8.

```
# /etc/mdns.allow
happy.me
(bare "me" will work, too, so is "*")

# /etc/nsswitch.conf
(among other lines ...)
hosts: files mdns dns
```

And we are good. Test with "getent ahosts bob.happy.me", will give all bob's addresses. All other programs that use glibc's resolver can resolve bob, too.